# HTML not displaying images from the same folder

Tags: html, css

I have a localhost website, and im trying to put some images but for some reason some of them work , but some don't an i don't know why as i'm using same path for both.

`<img src="../cndg.jpg" alt="city" />`

This one works

`<img src="../spiru.png" alt="rover" />`

This one doesn't even tough both images are in the same folder and have the same path

[image: these images have the same path but one doesn't work]

[image: I repeat all the images are in the same place]

[image]

Full code:

```
          <div class="card-header">
            <img src="../uradmonitor-logo.jpg" alt="rover" />
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <span class="tag tag-teal">
              Technology
            </span>
            <h4>uRADMonitor</h4>
            <p>uRADMonitor este o retea globala de aparate interconectate care masoara poluarea.Soluția se adresează atât gospodăriilor, spațiilor de producție și birourilor, cât și unei infrastructuri la nivel național, colectând date despre calitatea aerului.</p>
            <div class="user">
              <div class="user-info">
                <h5></h5>
                <small></small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <img src="../adifoto.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <span class="tag tag-purple">
              Photography
            </span>
            <h4>Adrian Chiru</h4>
            <p>
              The future can be scary, but there are ways to deal with that fear
            </p>
            <div class="user">
              <div class="user-info">
                <h5></h5>
                <small></small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe that image doesn't have `read` permission, it happens sometimes when you download an image from somewhere. In that case localhost won't load it.

Comment: Properly check the file names

Comment: Could also be a cache problem. [Error 304](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304) "is an implicit redirection to a cached resource."

Comment: Could also be that the extension is wrong or something

Comment: can you please upload your html code ?? the code you mentioned and screenshot both have different image sources

Comment: @Uzair added full code , the error is at the card-header of both cards

Comment: @Kokodoko and Maverick Fabroa  checked both file name and permissions and they are right

Comment: try ```ctrl+shift+del``` and try clearing cookies and cached images and then try again, and still if it doesn't work pls attach screenshot of your folder structure containing images

Comment: @Uzair still no luck

Comment: pls add screenshot of the folder structure

Comment: @Uzair added, note that there are a lot more images than in the screenshot

Comment: @EdiTheHigh because it's returning 404 that means the file is not found so there might be a slightest detail that you are missing on

Comment: ok and where is the index.html file??

Comment: @Uzair added, the views folder structure, i sent the wrong folder the page on wich the code is written is coop.ejs

Comment: ok, now if you could just show me which folder has index.html, maybe we could solve the issue

Comment: inside the views directory, in the folder pages is coop.ejs that is the html file, outside pages folder are the images

Comment: try with a different image in same folder as adifoto.jpg, does it work??

Comment: yes , in the same folder is cdng.jpg wich works

Comment: Then brother I think that the image is corrupt  and that you should try with a different image or open adifoto.jpg in paint and save it as a new image and see if that works for you!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to check it on Incognito mode, if it doesn't works then check it on a different browser, if that too doesn't work then..
Can you please share total code of it and attach a snapshot of your folder structure
?
**EDIT:** replace the image with another and keep the name same, I mean to say don't change anything in code. Just change the image. And rename it like previous. Is that worked?

Answer (score 0):

Brother I think your image file (the one that's not working maybe corrupted). It happens sometimes. Try to find another copy of the image, or at least edit the image in paint and re-save it. I once went through this same problem.